# Import Keystore protected with password inside glassfish

Tags: ssl, web, https, server, glassfish

I trying to put inside glassfish a keystore but it didn't work, it is located inside the config folder of my domain and I have putted into the glass fish panel the alias and the name of the key store, as you can see in te image below:

[glassfish panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lezo8.png)

can You help me?!

What I have to do?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You need to configure the port with keystore in server.xml(or equivalent configuration file)